# ES6 alternative for async.seq flow control

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using NodeJS, I'd previous use `async.seq` (which allows each passed in function to consume the return value of the previous function). For example, if I have an array of functions I want to pass a single value to the first, then the second, until I have a final result.

Now that async/await and generators are available, I've been trying to find if there's a native solution, but I'm not seeing anything.

Is there a way to flow an argument through a series of functions natively, or would it be easiest to still use the `async` package.

Note, in my specific use case, each function returns a promise.

Comment: With `async`/`await`, you would no longer keep an array of functions. You'd just call them and await their promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i usually do it with Array.prototype.reduce when dealing with Promises

```
const addOne = number => {
  console.log(number);
  return Promise.resolve(number + 1);
};

const sequence = [addOne, addOne];

sequence.reduce((previous, current) => previous.then(current), Promise.resolve(0))
  .then(finalValue => console.log(finalValue)); // 2
```

We start with an initial Promise.resolve(initialValue) and call the current promise once the previous one is resolved.

If you prefer async/await you could do it with a for loop but i find reduce more elegant

```
async function runSequence (initialValue) {
  let input = initialValue
  for (var i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
    input = await sequence[i](input)
  }
  return input
}

runSequence(0)
  .then(finalValue => console.log(finalValue)); // 2
```

Comment: I was looking at using `reduce` but had no luck yet, but this works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not ES6 (btw ES6 it's called ES2015, a long time ago already), but node.js already supports async/await. So this would be similar to what you could achieve with async.seq. Of course, you don't need to declare intermediate variables, it's up to you. And async.seq follows a specific convention that's not required here.

```
async function client(input) {
    const p1 = await process1(input)
    const p2 = await process2(p1)
    const p3 = await process3(p2)
    const p4 = await process4(p3)
    return p4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function called [compose](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/lib/blob/master/src/index.js#L204-L223), it implements reduce but promises are optional (things with `then` so any promise like results):

```
//not exported, checks if a value could be like promise
const promiseLike =
x =>
  (x!==undefined && typeof x.then === "function")
;
//not exported, if x is promise then fn is called with the
//  resolve of x
const ifPromise =
  (fn) =>
  (x) =>
    promiseLike(x)
      ?x.then(fn)
      :fn(x)
;
/**
* 
* takes 2 functions and turns it into:
* fn2(fn1(x)) when a value x is provided
* if x is a promse it will turn it into:
* x.then(x => fn2(fn1(x)))
* if fn1(x) is a promise it will turn it into:
* fn1(x).then(x => fn2(x))
* if both x and fn1(x) are promises:
* x.then(x => fn1(x)).then(x => fn2(x))
*/
const compose2 =
  fn1=>
  fn2=>
    x =>
      ifPromise
        (fn2)
        (
          ifPromise
            (fn1)
            (x)
        )
;

/**
turns an array of functions [fn1,fn2,fn3] into:
fn3(fn2(fn3(x)))
both x or any of the results of the functions can be a promise
If it is a promse then the next function will be called with
the resolve value of the promise.
If the promse is rejected the next function is not called
*/
const compose =
  fns =>
    fns.reduce(
      (acc,fn) => compose2(acc)(fn)
      ,x=>x//id function
    )
;
```

Usage example:

```
const searchHandler = search =>
  copose([
    x=>(showLoading(),x),
    makeSearchRequest,
    formatSearchResult,
    hideLoading
  ])(search)
  .catch(
    compose([
      showError,
      hideLoading
    ])
  )
```